# Function pointer as template argument: Can the calling convention (cdecl/stdcall) be deducted?

Tags: templates, c++14, calling-convention

I have a class like this

```
/**
  Some third party libraries with C interfaces have their own set of functions to allocate and free 
  heap memory buffers aligned to the specification of the library. This class helps to manage such
  buffers in a convenient RAII style

  @tparam Type The type of data to hold in the buffer
  @tparam SizeType The type used for sizes (in most cases either int or size_t)
  @tparam allocFunction A function to call that takes the number of bytes to allocate as argument and returns a pointer
                        of Type* to the allocated memory
  @tparam freeFunction A function to call that takes a void* pointer and frees the previously allocated memory
 */
template <typename Type, typename SizeType, Type* (*allocFunction)(SizeType), void (*freeFunction)(void*)>
class GenericScopedBuffer
```

This worked fine until I now tried to update one of our older products that is still built as a 32 Windows version. We use some library that has their allocation/deallocation functions defined as `__stdcall` types and passing them to this class template like e.g.

```
GenericScopedBuffer<char, int, stdcallAllocFunction, stdcallFreeFunction>
```

leads to a compiler error like `C2440: 'specialization': cannot convert from 'void (__stdcall *)(void *)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(void *)'`

The obvious reason is that the x86 compiler assumes a function pointer declared like that as a pointer to a `__cdecl` function. Now as this class template should in fact work with a function pointer any kind of function I wonder if there is a way to deduct the calling convention type from the function passed in. However, __stdcall or __cdecl are not really types but more like hints to the compiler, right?

So what would be a good way to enable this in a cross-platform and generic way?

Comment: Assuming that your default convention is `cdecl`, when you write the function template it automatically add the `__cdecl`. `__cdecl` and `__stdcall` are not just hints, but the way the function is built and called and that's why you can't cast between `cdecl` function and `stdcall` function without getting some stack errors. Instead, you can use a simple `typename` and check it with `std::is_function`.

Comment: Yes I know about the fundamental difference between `__cdecl` and `__stdcall`. However what do you mean by "you can use a simple typename and check it with std::is_function". Would you have some short demo code for me to elaborate on this?

Answer (score 2):

`void (__stdcall *)(void *)` and `void (__cdecl *)(void *)` are two different types as far as MSVC is concerned. These qualifiers are a kind of pre-standard way to specify *language linkage*. Recall that an `extern "C"` function is different from an `extern "C++"` function which is different from `extern "FORTRAN"` function, even though some compilers let you get away with mixing up those.

There is a couple of ways to deal with this.

You can specialise your template for `__cdecl` functions.

You can tell the compiler you don't care what the type is:

```
template <auto allocFunction, auto freeFunction> class GenericScopedBuffer
```

If you don't have access to the modern version of C++, you can parameterize by function type:

```
template <typename AllocFuncT, AllocFuncT allocFunction, 
          typename FreeFuncT, FreeFuncT freeFunction> class GenericScopedBuffer
```

but then of course you have to specify the type by hand. You can use `decltype` for that, possibly combined with a silly macro like

```
#define TV(x) decltype(x), (x)
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately we use C++14 and auto template parameters are a C++17 feature – I updated the tag on the original question, otherwise this would have been my solution of choice. The "silly macro" solution seems like a way to go, altough it depends on a silly macro :D – which I prefer to avoid